# Should I install gravel or artificial turf in a trapezoid-shaped yard?

Tags: gravel, weeds

I have a trapezoidal back yard. Part of it has some old artificial turf on top of paved surface. This surface isn't completely even, but with turf it's not quite visible. Another part has grass.

I would like to keep it consistent i.e. just gravel or turf - but it's getting quite challenging for me to understand what to do with it. Ideally, I don't want any grass material in my garden. So, I am expecting that I might have to maw it clean, level it, lay membrane (simple weed-suppressing, NOT polypropylene), and then gravel on top. But I am worried that it might make the backyard look out of place considering part of it has concrete/pavement.

Any thoughts or suggestion from anyone?

Comment: how is the trapezoid shape important?

Comment: A photo of the area would be helpful, but in fact, many gardens have different surfacing within them, with perhaps a paved patio area, then gravel with stepping stones in it, sometimes also with lawn, for example.